# Excel truncates function return when using PyXll

Tags: python, excel, excel-addins, pyxll

We have a function in python that is called in Excel using PyXll Add-in. To do so, the function is called using this code:

```py
import myfunction
from pyxll import xl_func
import pandas as pd

@xl_func('float[][], float[]', auto_resize=True)
def myfunction_xl(
    x: Iterable,
    y: Iterable,
) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
    (
        df1,
        df2,
        df3,
    ) = myfunction(x, y)
    return (
        df1,
        df2,
        df3,
    )
```

This calls the code of `myfunction` which returns after some computation a tuple of three dataframes of different sizes and columns.

The function call works fine in Excel, however the three dataframes are somehow truncated and not displayed with their content.

[image]

The same thing happens when calling some other functions which return a long list. Can you please help me figure out how to fix the display? thanks.